# Updating store value with computed property with Vue2 and Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am using Vue2 and Vuex in my simple test ecommerce project. I have products with a default price value as $0.  In my product show view, I have a computed property that calculates the price when a user selects the size measurements.  The calculations are working and I can display `calculatedPrice` to my view, but I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around updated the store `property.price` value.  When I add to cart, it adds the default $0.

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

import Vue from "vue";
import VuexPersist from 'vuex-persist';

import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

import VueRouter from "vue-router";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: require('./routes.js')
});

const vuexLocalStorage = new VuexPersist({
    key: 'vuex', // The key to store the state on in the storage provider.
    storage: window.sessionStorage, // or window.sessionStorage or localForage
    // Function that passes the state and returns the state with only the objects you want to store.
    // reducer: state => state,
    // Function that passes a mutation and lets you decide if it should update the state in localStorage.
    // filter: mutation => (true)
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        products: [],
        cart: [],
        order: {}
    },
    plugins: [vuexLocalStorage.plugin],
    mutations: {
        updateProducts(state, products) {
            state.products = products;
        },
        addToCart(state, product) {
            let productInCartIndex = state.cart.findIndex(item => item.slug === product.slug);
            if (productInCartIndex !== -1) {
                state.cart[productInCartIndex].quantity++;
                return;
            }

            product.quantity = 1;
            state.cart.push(product);
        },
        removeFromCart(state, index) {
            state.cart.splice(index, 1);
        },
        updateOrder(state, order) {
            state.order = order;
        },
        updateCart(state, cart) {
            state.cart = cart;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getCategories({commit}) {
            // fetch the categories and attached products from the api
            axios.get('/api/products')
                .then((response) => {
                    commit('updateProducts', response.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => console.error(error));
        },
        clearCart({commit}) {
            commit('updateCart', []);
        }
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    el: '#app',
    created() {
        store.dispatch('getCategories')
            .then(_ => {})
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }
});
```

**Show.vue**

```
<template>
...
<div class="mt-3">
    <h2 class="sr-only">Product information</h2>
    <p v-text="formatCurrency(product.price)" class="text-3xl text-gray-900"></p>
</div>
...
<div class="mt-6">
    <h3>Size</h3>

    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
        <div class="mt-4 sm:mt-0 sm:pr-9">
            <label for="width" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Outer Width:</label>
            <select v-model="width" id="width" name="width"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md">
                <option value="3">3"</option>
                <option value="4">4"</option>
                <option value="5">5"</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-4 sm:mt-0 sm:pr-9">
            <label for="height" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Outer
                Height:</label>
            <select v-model="height" id="height" name="height"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md">
                <option value="3">3"</option>
                <option value="4">4"</option>
                <option value="5">5"</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-4 sm:mt-0 sm:pr-9">
            <label for="length" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Length:</label>
            <select v-model="length" id="length" name="length"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md">
                <option value="10">10'</option>
                <option value="11">11'</option>
                <option value="12">12'</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        formatCurrency(amount) {
            amount = (amount / 100);
            return amount.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'});
        },
    },
    computed: {
        products() {
            return this.$store.state.products;
        },
        product() {
            return this.products.find(product => product.slug === this.$route.params.slug);
        },
        calculatedPrice() { // I need to update product.price in store with this value
            return ((((this.width + (this.height * 2)) * 12) / 144) * 25) * this.length;
        },
    },

    data() {
        return {
            height: '4',
            width: '4',
            length: '10'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code segment seems to be quite suspicious to me that it does not trigger the vue's reactive system.

```
addToCart(state, product) {
  let productInCartIndex = state.cart.findIndex(item => item.slug === product.slug);
  // ...
}
```

I would rather try on cloning the object and using the `Vue.set`. Something like this.

```
import Vue from "vue";

{
  addToCart: (state, product) => {
    let productInCartIndex = state.cart.findIndex(
      (item) => item.slug === product.slug
    );

    if (productInCartIndex !== -1) {
      const target = { ...state.cart[productInCartIndex] };

      target.quantity++;

      Vue.set(state.cart, productInCartIndex, target);

      return;
    }

    state.cart.push({ ...product, quantity: 1 });
  };
}
```